# Pandas Pivot table converts float to int

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion, pivot-table

I found weird behavior of pandas when converting data frame to pivot table.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'car_id': {0: 'Trabant', 1: 'Buick', 2: 'Dodge'}, 'car_order': {0: 2, 1: 1, 2: 14}, 'car_name': {0: 'Trabant', 1: 'Buick', 2: 'Dodge'}, 'car_rank': {0: 111111317.29, 1: 1111112324.0, 2: 1111112324.5}})
table = df.pivot_table(index=['car_id', 'car_name', 'car_order'], columns=[],values=['car_rank'], fill_value='',dropna=True)
print table

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'car_id': {0: 'Trabant', 1: 'Buick', 2: 'Dodge'}, 'car_order': {0: 2, 1: 1, 2: 14}, 'car_name': {0: 'Trabant', 1: 'Buick', 2: 'Dodge'}, 'car_rank': {0: 17.29, 1: 24.0, 2: 24.5}})
table1 = df1.pivot_table(index=['car_id', 'car_name', 'car_order'], columns=[],values=['car_rank'], fill_value='',dropna=True)
print table1
```

Result output:

```
Table
                              car_rank
car_id  car_name car_order            
Buick   Buick    1          1111112324
Dodge   Dodge    14         1111112324
Trabant Trabant  2           111111317

Table 1
                            car_rank
car_id  car_name car_order          
Buick   Buick    1             24.00
Dodge   Dodge    14            24.50
Trabant Trabant  2             17.29
```

Do you know why in **Table** are values converted to int and for **Table 1** values stay as float?

pandas 0.18.0 , python 2.7.9

Comment: If you check dtypes of values, you will see int instead of float.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is result of my observations of `pandas 0.18.0`:

Source code of `pandas/tools/pivot.py` definition of `pivot_table()` lines: 141-142:

```
if fill_value is not None:
    table = table.fillna(value=fill_value, downcast='infer')
```

This is exactly what happened to your pivoted DF:

```
In [78]: df.fillna('', downcast='infer')
Out[78]:
    car_id car_name  car_order    car_rank
0  Trabant  Trabant          2   111111317
1    Buick    Buick          1  1111112324
2    Dodge    Dodge         14  1111112324
```

**Types:**

```
In [48]: df.fillna('', downcast='infer').dtypes
Out[48]:
car_id       object
car_name     object
car_order     int64
car_rank      int64
dtype: object
```

Interestingly enough  - if you use `pivot_table()` properly (i.e. for pivoting) - it works correctly:

```
In [81]: df.pivot_table(index=['car_id', 'car_order'], columns=['car_name'], values=['car_rank'],dropna=True, fill_value='')
Out[81]:
                       car_rank
car_name                  Buick         Dodge      Trabant
car_id  car_order
Buick   1         1111112324.00
Dodge   14                      1111112324.50
Trabant 2                                     111111317.29
```

PS I still can't understand why are you using pivot_table in that strange way - what are you going to achieve?

Comment: Ok, this was just sample of using pivot table, it depends on user input. Before calling pivot table changed DF like **df = df.fillna(value='', inplace=False, downcast=None)** and then call pivot table without fillna

Comment: So `downcast='infer'` is treating as float32 instead of float64?  Or at least that seems implied given that float32 has about 7 digits of precision and df has the problem but not df1.

Comment: @JohnE, it downcasted it to `int64` - see my updated answer - `Types`

Comment: Exactly.  What I'm noting is that fillna seems "smart enough" to know that downcasting df1 to int64 would lose info, but not "smart enough" to know that same thing for df.  It's roughly consistent with fillna viewing the numbers as float32 rather than float64, but I'm just speculating here as to that being the cause.